# How to enable hiding grub menu on a dual-boot system?

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

With GRUB 2, you seem to be able to hide the startup menu (unless someone presses a certain button). But unfortunately grub disables this for multi-OS systems, I've looked up a few other pages.

But after one which made me have to re-install Ubuntu, I gave up. Does anyone know how this can be done on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: If you hide the grub menu, you will not be able to boot into Windows.

Comment: I thought that the answer would be explained by the description of how to set the GRUB variables in `/etc/default/grub` in this [**GRUB2 help section**](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Configuring_GRUB_2). I tried using the variables the way I thought the help said, but it does not work for me. Maybe you'll have better luck? If you figure it out on your own, please answer your own question to let us know what you did.

Comment: But to unhide it you just have to hold a key during startup, correct?

Comment: Yes i tried the variables too. i think they disabled it deliberatly.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/117525/hide-grub2-menu-unless-you-hold-down-shift-key-how-to-make-this-happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to do the same and I found great help in the Ubuntu Forums, particularly in [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1287602) thread.

Assuming you did the right thing with `/etc/default/grub`, correctly setting `GRUB_TIMEOUT` and `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` (I'd say respectively to 0 and 5) and even `GRUB_DEFAULT` to specify the default image to boot, here's the procedure to have it work the right way.

1. Add those lines

   ```
   GRUB_FORCE_HIDDEN_MENU="true"
   export GRUB_FORCE_HIDDEN_MENU
   ```

   to the end of `/etc/default/grub`
2. Backup your `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` and overwrite it with the version found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1083280/).
3. Run the command: `sudo update-grub` to update the settings.
4. Test it! To show the menu you have to hold the `SHIFT` key at startup.

This problem is related to the multi OS setup and editing the script is one of the way to correct that.

PS: This answer is exatcly the same given to another identical [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117525/hide-grub2-menu-unless-you-hold-down-shift-key-how-to-make-this-happen)

Comment: I'm new to this but i think i did it.

Answer (score 0):

I provided a new workaround at the original question posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117525/hide-grub2-menu-unless-you-hold-down-shift-key-how-to-make-this-happen/768961#768961).
Hope it helps.