# Grub menu does not hide though GRUB_TIMEOUT=0

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, uefi

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and have dual boot windows 11. I'm trying to hide grub menu  while booting and automatically boot ubuntu as I have seen that can be done with changing GRUB_TIMEOUT to 0 in /etc/default/grub and run sudo update-grub but grub doesn't hide and sets time to 10 seconds. I am able to change the timer to be different even -1 but 0 does not work for whatever reason. I have also come across the solution that in /etc/grub.d/40_custom I should add at the end of the file: set default="0" set timeout=0
. While this works I'm concerned that when some error occurs I would not be able to get into  ubuntu advanced options because it disables grub menu in the boot time so I decided not to use it.

Here is my /etc/default/grub:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash loglevel=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
```

I would be really grateful for any advice as to why my grub menu does not hide.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/a/882268/1684306 or https://askubuntu.com/a/161707/1684306

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get my GRUB menu to be hidden, AND have the shift or esc keys show the hidden GRUB menu at boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879881/how-can-i-get-my-grub-menu-to-be-hidden-and-have-the-shift-or-esc-keys-show-the)

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank YOU!!!