# Is there way to boot from Windows by default?

Tags: grub2, windows

When the computer loads up, it shows a list of what to boot from. Is there a way to hide this and automatically boot from Windows unless a key is pressed?

Comment: Are you running on dual-boot? Or have Ubuntu installed inside Windows with WUBI?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Grub-Customizer application](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/grub-customizer-30-released.html) to set the default boot option as follows:

1. [Follow this guide](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/how-to-add-a-ppa-to-software-sources-in-ubuntu) to add the following Source to your **Software Sources.**

   ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
2. Let the refresh happen. (Will update the index of apps)
3. Using the Softare Centre, install **Grub-Customizer**.
4. Open Grub-Customizer, under the *General Settings tab*, select the **Default Entry** as Windows.
5. Then you can hide the menu and change the timeout to something like 3 seconds.
6. Save and reboot!
7. While booting, hold `SHIFT` to present grub (boot menu)

---

Steps 1 - 3 can be accomplished using the Accessories > **Terminal** by running the following three commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

---

Editing the **/boot/grub/grub.cfg** and **/etc/default/grub** files manually is not usually recommended... BUT if you must: [Have a look at this Question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117525/hide-grub2-menu-unless-you-hold-down-shift-key-how-to-make-this-happen)

Answer (score 0):

[Grub Customizer](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/grub-customizer-30-released.html) is a graphical settings manager for GRUB2 and BURG.

You can set Windows as default. Among the other Grub Customizer features are:

```
- edit the menu entries (reorder, rename, add or remove entries)
- change the default boot entry
- change menu visibility and timeout
- disable recovery entries
- change GRUB resolution, menu colors or background image
- GRUB repair & configuration using a Live CD
- Advanced options like booting an ISO, changing kernel parameters and lots more
```

A new Grub Customizer version has been release: 3.0, which brings the following new features:

```
- entries can be moved free now
- integrated settings dialog
- new partition chooser
- context menu
- multi selection
- trash instead of checkboxes
- entry editor
- graphical error handling
- reset functionality
- warning when trying to remove script - or system entries
```

Grub Customizer is considered a stable application, but be very careful when using it and make sure you know what you're doing! Messing with GRUB2/BURG can cause the system not to boot!