# How to boot directly to Ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I have both Ubuntu and Windows installed. Can I setting GRUB to automatically boot to Ubuntu, and only show OS list when I hold some special key?

I use Windows rarely but I still need it.

According to suggestion answer, there is nothing I can do to solve my question.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/117525/hide-grub2-menu-unless-you-hold-down-shift-key-how-to-make-this-happen/117538#117538

Comment: Grub menu still won't show up if I hold SHIFT key..