# How to launch windows on default and Linux by choice?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, launcher, bootloader, multiple-desktops

I'm using Windows for everything, but I want to check and learn Linux also. My computer is also used by my family. Is there any possibility to run Windows by default (without any choosing) and Ubuntu on demand (for example when I click F6 or something like that on startup)?

Edit: Any of the answers don't work for me (new version of Ubuntu). Anyone?

Comment: Is your question about booting by default to windows instead of Ubuntu ? If yes, have a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader/52990#52990). If you want to fiddle around with Ubuntu, you could also install it through a Virtual Machine in Windows, like `WMWare Player` or `VirtualBox`. That way, you get a sandboxed environment where you can mess around without breaking your system

Comment: I followed Ploutox's link and set Windows as default choice in grub2, but what I wanted to do is something like that:

**IF I want to use Windows:**

1. I start the computer.

That's all. No menus, no choosing.


**IF I want to use Ubuntu:**

1. I start the computer.

2. I click something (like F6, F7 etc.), then I choose Ubuntu.

Is it even possible? Maybe change of bootloader or configuration of it?

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/117589/312937) could help. in short: use GRUB2, set both timeouts to 0 (better try with booting Ubuntu first)

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your computer boot into Windows by default, you'll have to change GRUB's config file. While you could do that from the config file as root, I would recommend using GRUB Customizer, since it is a graphical interface for editing the boot order and a few other things, like the appearance of GRUB when you're selecting an OS to boot into.

Try the following in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

If GRUB Customizer doesn't show up in Ubuntu's applications, then you will be able to launch it with

```
grub-customizer
```

via a terminal or the Alt+F2 run command shortcut.