# How to hide grub unless key is pressed?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu

I have 2 OSs Windows 8 and Kubuntu 16.04. Kubuntu is my primary OS.
I would like my laptop to boot directly into Kubuntu, unless I press SHIFT key during boot to make Grub menu visible.
Again. I want grub menu with OSs list visible, only when I press SHIFT or any other key during boot.

I followed instructions in [Hide GRUB2 menu UNLESS you hold down Shift key: how to make this happen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117525/hide-grub2-menu-unless-you-hold-down-shift-key-how-to-make-this-happen) and it didn't work as I wanted.

I don't even want to feel that the grub is there, so the following values are required.

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0.0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.0
```

Apparently linux doesn't give you the freedom it tells you it does. Because if it did /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober wouldn't change the timeout on its own.

```
if [ "\${timeout}" = 0 ]; then    
set timeout=10
```

Is there any easy way to achieve what I want? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

It does not work.
Additionaly according to
    info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

```
'GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT'
     Wait this many seconds before displaying the menu.  If <ESC> is
     pressed during that time, display the menu and wait for input
     according to 'GRUB_TIMEOUT'.  If a hotkey associated with a menu
     entry is pressed, boot the associated menu entry immediately.  If
     the timeout expires before either of these happens, display the
     menu for the number of seconds specified in 'GRUB_TIMEOUT'             before
     booting the default entry.

     If you set 'GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT', you should also set
     'GRUB_TIMEOUT=0' so that the menu is not displayed at all unless
     <ESC> is pressed.

     This option is unset by default, and is deprecated in favour of the
     less confusing 'GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown' or
     'GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden'.
```

I set GRUB_TIMEOUT=5 and GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=3 and grub menu is shown for... 3 seconds!?

Clearly people behind grub, screwed it up.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

Then, when you switch the computer on, pres `ESC` to enter to the boot menu, otherwise, the computer will boot in the default selection.

For sake of simplicity, you can change those values easily with [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

In the tab **General**, click on **advanced settings**, then, select active the following keys and update the values to:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT = 5
GRUB_TIMEOUT = 0
```

Optional, to display a counter showing the remaining seconds while you can press `ESC`, set:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET = false
```

[image: GRUB settings dialog]

Comment: not working, this only shows grub menu for 5 seconds instead of 10

Comment: @frnhr Does this happen even if you set `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10`?

Answer (score 0):

To enable GRUB hidden timeout, open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt install gksu
```

(in case it is not already installed, alternatively use nano editor)

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Remove `#` from the front of the line `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`,

that the line afterwards exactly reads : `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`.

Save the change and close the file - now execute this command :

```
gksudo gedit /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
```

Change timeout from 10 to 0 ...

```
if [ "\${timeout}" = 0 ]; then  
  set timeout=10
```

that it afterwards exactly reads :

```
if [ "\${timeout}" = 0 ]; then  
  set timeout=0
```

Save the change and close the file.

Update the GRUB configuration :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart the system ... now it should boot directly into Kubuntu.

Comment: Ok, but if I want to boot into Windows, what should I do?

Comment: @justmatt : After starting the PC press the Shift key to show the GRUB menu and select Windows to boot.

Comment: I did as you advised and I can't show grub menu by pressing Shift key.

Comment: @justmatt : Did you press and HOLD the Shift key ? Alternatively check whether pressing the Esc key brings up the GRUB menu. Another alternative is to boot into BIOS and select Windows from there. :)

Comment: Yes and it does not show up;(