# How to set GRUB timeout to 0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04

I tried to update my grub config file to timeout to 0 value, so OS starts quickly. I modified `/etc/default/grub` configuration file on my Ubuntu 18.04 and then ran:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and it didn't work. I also ran:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig
sudo update-grub
```

but they didn't work.

I searched a lot on the web to solve this issue, but all guides say to run the update-grub command to update grub by `/etc/default/grub` config file.
I don't know if is Ubuntu 18.04 that handles grub files in a different way, but I cannot update my grub with my parameters.

This is my `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
# info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your modified grub config file. Otherwise we're just trying to guess what you did.

Comment: Do you have other distributions installed (dual boot)?

Comment: it didn't work mean that my grub timeout is still set to 10 sec as by default @Melebius

Comment: I have windows in the same ssd and other distros installed on other hdd, but last month i had fedora 27 (instead of ubuntu 18) and it worked when i changed grub config file, so i think the other distros aren't the causes of this behavior  @mook765

Comment: @Bob91 Sounds like you run `update-grub` in the wrong distribution. Or, if installed in legacy-mode, you boot to the wrong drive. Installing multiple Linux-distribution can lead to confusion when it comes to the boot-loader (Grub). I always install Grub in only one distro, in additional distros I don't install Grub at all.

Comment: The file in use is : `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` . Editing "/etc/defaults/grub file" does nothing.

Comment: @KnudLarsen The file `/etc/default/grub` is translated into `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` using the `update-grub` program. However, it might be actually useful if OP checked the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` whether it gets updated.

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: Do not change to 0. When later you need to get into grub, you will not be able to. Change to 3 sec or whatever is just long enough for you to press key to get grub menu when you have boot issues.

Comment: @oldfred my problem is that i have bluetooth mouse and keyboard, so i can't access to grub options even if timeout is set to 10.

Comment: done ! @Melebius

Comment: A time out of `1` works for me. I have to have finger hovering over `Escape` key during boot if I need to change distro or kernel version.

Comment: This question describes almost the same problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/117525/hide-grub2-menu-unless-you-hold-down-shift-key-how-to-make-this-happen

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1273764

Answer (score 18):

In `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file there is a condition, almost at the end of the file, that sets the timeout to 10 if the timeout is set to 0. In other words, if you set the timeout to 0 in your `/etc/default/grub` and then update grub, the condition above reset it to 10 seconds.

```sh
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
     set timeout=10
fi
```

However, `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is a read-only file and I cannot remove that condition. I made some tests with different values of the timeout in `/etc/default/grub`. I tried with 1ms (0.001), 0.1s and 1s and I found out that values below 1 (like 0.1 and 0.001) work in the same way and almost like timeout set to 0.

Comment: `work in the same way and almost like timeout` that's because math in bash supports integers only. The shortest timeout that would make a difference is `1`.

Comment: The GRUB manual says `Set [GRUB_TIMEOUT] to '0' to boot immediately without displaying the menu`, so this is either a patch added downstream by Ubuntu, or the GRUB project forgot to update their documentation. I'll have to set it to 1 instead, but it sucks.

Comment: I found more info. That conditional comes from the "os prober" module. If you don't need it, disable it with `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true`, then you can set timeout to zero.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, the problem was that my system didn't support "recordfail" which caused a separate block to get added to the grub.cfg which defaults to a timeout of 30 seconds. The relevant code in `/etc/grub.d/00_header`:

```sh
if [ "$recordfail_broken" = 1 ]; then
  cat << EOF
if lsefi; then
  set timeout=${GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT:-30}
  if [ x\$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
  fi
fi
EOF
```

The fix is simply to add a value for `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT` in `/etc/default/grub` and run `update-grub` again. For example:

```sh
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Adjusted timeout for system which doesn't support recordfail
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=2

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to `0`.

The part overwriting timeout value is written in `ajust_timeout` function in the top of `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`.

```
ajust_timeout () {
...
if [ "\${timeout}" = 0]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
...
}
```

So, you can set the value by editing the file and comment out if-block.

Comment: Or you can do what @mook765 says and override the timeout in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` instead, which is more correct because it's a file that is meant to be customized by the user.

Answer (score 4):

Like the other answers say, uncomment `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` and run `update-grub`. Then comment out the

```
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
```

section in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. In vim you can just override the read-only property with an exclamation point `:x!`. Or you can run

```
sudo chmod +w /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo vim /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo chmod -w /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

to temporarily have write permission while editing the file.

Comment: You are right, but i think everytime you update grub (manually or when there are any os upgrade) the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` will recreated with the condition above.

Comment: That is true, the file is overwritten on update, as I experienced recently.

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` and run `update-grub` again.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=-1

Comment: `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=-1` worked on Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: This option is unset by default and deprecated in favour of `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE`

Answer (score 1):

We can simply add the line

```
set timeout=0
```

to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, make the file executable with

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

to generate the new `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`-file. The `set timeout`-command we added is the last `set timeout`-command in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` now, that is what counts.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is experienced in both Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 and even though some of the other answers has solutions that work as expected, either files that has on the header an "do not edit this file" notice such as the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` are manually edited, or the changes are not persistent after system updates or regenerating grub configuration files (at least weren't for me). Here's a step by step of what I've been doing to change such behaviour in a persistent fashion.

#### Step 1 - Modify the template file `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`

Grub uses some template files located at `/etc/grub.d` in order to generate the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Edit the file with your editor of choice...

```
# vim /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
```

... and either comment or remove the lines below that override the timeout when it's set to zero.

```
if [ "\${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
```

#### Step 2 - Modify the file `/etc/default/grub`

Grub uses this file to set configuration values in order to generate the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Edit the file with your editor of choice...

```
# vim /etc/default/grub
```

... and set the timeout for zero (use the second option if the `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` is set to `hidden`)

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

#### Step 3 - Generate the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

```
# update-grub2
```

... and after the next machine reboot the expected behaviour is having a timeout of zero on grub menu.

Comment: Why commenting or removing the lines that set the timeout to 10 in `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` when you can edit it to set it to zero instead and save yourself from doing step 2? Or even better, instead of editing this file, edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` as @mook765 suggests

Answer (score 0):

You can set `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to `-1`.

> Ex:`GRUB_TIMEOUT="-1"`

Comment: 'GRUB_TIMEOUT'
     Boot the default entry this many seconds after the menu is
     displayed, unless a key is pressed.  The default is '5'.  Set to
     '0' to boot immediately without displaying the menu, or to '-1' to
     wait indefinitely.
from command `info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration`

Comment: @GiceuCassiano your solution is the complete opposite of setting the timeout to zero because -1 waits forever until the user selects an option. It is therefore as if you specified infinity.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to add

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
```

to `/etc/default/grub`.

All other solutions will be reset on grub updates.

Comment: This solution works when the timeout is set to 30 seconds because the 30 seconds timeout comes from the default value of GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT, which is used when the first attempt to boot fails if I recall correctly (I might be wrong). Also, not all other solutions will be reset on grub updates.