# Ubuntu 18.04 slow boot - Delay before loading GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04

A week or two ago, My ubuntu laptop *(ASUS X556U)* has started to experience a 10-30 second delay before reaching the first purple screen *(GRUB loaded)*. I think this is happening since a package update in the last weeks.

The output of `systemd-analyze time` is

```
Startup finished in
5.633s (firmware) + 2.423s (loader) + 3.604s (kernel) + 15.727s (userspace) = 27.388s

graphical.target reached after 15.350s in userspace
```

so the *loading time of **Linux*** are good/fast enough for me.

*How can I regain my usual boot time¿?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced a similar problem on my Lenovo X220 some weeks ago.

In my case, the problem was the default GRUB_TIMEOUT, which makes the system wait for 10 seconds before loading grub. You can check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036957/298047) for more info.
I managed to regain the usual boot speed by lowering GRUB_TIMEOUT to 1 second.

To achieve that, edit Grub's configuration file `/etc/default/grub`, and change the value of `GRUB_TIMEOUT` *around line 8* and set it to **1**:

- Run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
- Find the line *(arround line 8)* with `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` and change it to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=1`
- Save changes and exit your editor
- Run `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot your machine

Then you should be enjoying a fast boot again.

Comment: Wow thanks, thanks, thanks and thanks !! You saved my day, I was going mad... Searching and finding nothing. Now i regained my ~30 sec boot time

Comment: That should be the default config. I don't understand why it is configured to wait 10 seconds before starting to boot.

Comment: Maybe, in such situation accessing grub boot menu will be substantially harder.